# Convert javascript array to ko.observablearray and bind to template

Tags: knockout.js

I want to convert a javascript array that is in data.js file to ko.observable array and bind it to list tag

HTML

```
<script type="text/html" id="profileListTemplate">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>            
        </li>
    </script>

   <h1>Profile Viewer</h1>

    <div class="tabbable tabs-left" id="profilesTabViewer">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="profileTab" data-bind="template: { name: 'profileListTemplate'}">
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="profileContent">
        </div>
    </div>`
```

### data.js

```
    var data = [
    {
     'id': '1',
     'firstName': 'Megan',
     'lastName': 'Fox',
     'picture': 'images/01.jpg',
     'bio': 'Megan Denise Fox was born May 16, 1986 in Rockwood, Tennessee. ... 
    },
    ....
    ];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain and simple:

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray(data);
```

Here is your updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simonlevasseur/qr7PL/

Note that in your template, you shouldn't put: people.firstName
It should just be firstName as explained here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: Thanks Simon. When I try to bind the values still I'm facing issues not sure what am I doing wrong. I'm new to knockout your comments would be of great value to me. It would be nice if you could send me a working example based on this scenario jsfiddle.net/du3QX

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply this:

```
var list = ko.observableArray(data);
```

I use this approach when building an underlying array.  I then push the underlying all at once.  Another construct might be:

```
var list = ko.observableArray([]);
list.push(data);
```

But, you may need to make each property observable, in which case you could use the Knockout mapping plugin as gaurav suggests, or you could simply write your own mapper.  A good example of how to do that can be found in John Papa's course from Pluralsight: *Single Page Apps with HTML5, Web API, Knockout and jQuery*.

Comment: Thanks for your feed backs Eric. When I try to bind the values still I'm facing issues not sure what am I doing wrong. I'm new to knockout your comments would be of great value to me.

It would be nice if you could send me a working example based on this scenario

http://jsfiddle.net/du3QX/

Comment: @Vimal I updated your fiddle, but I eliminated the template binding just to show you that `fromJSON()` isn't necessary.  Otherwise, Simon LeVasseur's fiddle is working fine.  If you're still having trouble, please post a fuller example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromJSON` function of knockout which will convert JSON string to object. In your scenario you can do something like:

```
//converting your json string to array of objects
var list = ko.fromJSON(data); 

//creating observable array from array of objects.
var observableList = ko.observableArray(list);
```

You should check [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) also.

Comment: Thanks for your feed backs Gaurav. When I try to bind the values still I'm facing issues not sure what am I doing wrong. I'm new to knockout your comments would be of great value to me.

It would be nice if you could send me a working example based on this scenario

http://jsfiddle.net/du3QX/